# Calling C++ Functions from Python with pybind11 (or similar library)

Tags: python, c++

I'm writing a C++ project and am interested in adding a Python scripting system for automation of certain tasks. If I have a function like this:

```
void alert(_msg);

std::cout >> _msg;
```

Using pybind11 (or another option if you find it better) I would like to be able to call it trough Python and pass arguments to it:

```
alert("This is printed text")
```

I've done tons of research already and know about libraries such as Boost.Python, ESC:Python, SWIG, etc, as well as the embedding capabilities built into python. However, I'm having difficulty getting started in any of these technologies. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here are a load of options with (basic) examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python?rq=1